# How to open second NSWindow?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xib

I'm trying to open a second NSWindow when an NSTableViewCell is clicked. So far, here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    IndiFlightWC.loadWindow()
    IndiFlightWC.showWindow(nil)
    IndiFlightWC.setMap(indiFlight: FlightList[row]!)
    return true
}
```

and the IndiFlightWC is initialized like this:

```
var IndiFlightWC = IndiFlightWindowController()
```

I put a breakpoint in the windowDidLoad of my IndiFlightWindowController and it never reaches it. So my question is how to do you properly display a new window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your init method is almost certainly incorrect.

If you look at the [documentation for NSWindowController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller), you'll see there are four different init methods listed there.  All of them take parameters.

Is your `IndiFlightWindowController` xib included in your project?  Why not try `let indiFlightWC = IndiFlightWindowController(windowNibName: "IndiFlightWindowController")` and see what happens.

A couple other tips:

1) variable names should start with lower case.  Use `indiFlightWC` instead of `IndiFlightWC` as a variable name.  Caps should be for classes.

2) [`loadWindow` isn't needed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowcontroller/1535137-loadwindow) because `showWindow` should automatically call `loadWindow`.